# retrieve child object by evaluating grandchildren object in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models, `User` and `Conversation` related to each other with a many-to-many relationship, many users to many conversations.

On my models I have:

`User`:

```
public function conversation() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Conversation');
}
```

`Conversation`:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
}
```

So I could get the conversations a user has by : `$user->conversation;` and vice versa, retrieve the users a conversation has by `$conversation->users`, works like a charm. The problem is that I want a way to retrieve all users a certain user has made contact before, in few words, something like:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$talkedUsers = $user->conversation->user.
```

And also a way to check all the conversation user 'x' has made with user 'y' ('if any')

```
$userX = User::find(1);
$userY = 2;
    
$talkedUser = $userX->conversation->where('user.id', '=', $userY);
```

Obviously, the code above won't work. I wish to know if something like this is possible to accomplish without adding a complex raw query, I hope is possible only using only `QueryBuilder`.

Comment: Did you try this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through The title of route question is misleading. You seem to ask for hierarchical recursive structures, but your question is more basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that I want a way to retrieve all users a certain user
> has made contact before,

`$user->conversation` is actually a collection of conversations, it is better to use plural i.e. `$user->conversations`. Then you can use higher order messages to deal with multiple objects at once. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages for more information

```
$users = $user->conversations->flatMap->users->unique('id');
```

`flatMap` combines multiple `User` collections retrieved from multiple `Conversation` objects into one collection of `User` objects then to remove duplicate users, you can use `unique('id')`

> And also a way to check all the conversation user 'x' has made with
> user 'y' ('if any')

First you should query all conversations from x then filter only conversations that have relationships with y.

```
$userX = User::find($x);

$conversations = $userX->conversations()
    ->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($y) {
        $query->where('users.id', $y);
    })
    ->get();
```